# How to use specific version of web3

Tags: web3js, truffle

I have listed the versions of web3 versions installed in my system

```
 npm ls web3
        inbox@1.0.0 /home/mdvenkatesh/Desktop/etherium solidity programes/inbox
        +-- truffle-hdwallet-provider@0.0.6
        | `-- web3@0.18.4 
        `-- web3@1.0.0-beta.26
```

In my code i am using `async await`.  i want to compile my code and run

But i am getting error

```
accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
           ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

1) How to use `version 1` without uninstalling the previous version of web3

2)In  My previous projects i am using promise's if i uninstall the old version will it effect my previous code while compiling

3) I tried to remove  using npm but showing me error

```
npm remove web3@0.18.4
npm WARN truffle-hdwallet-provider@0.0.6 requires a peer of truffle@4.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN inbox@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not related to web3js at all. You need to mark function(lets name the function ‘check’) as ‘async’ before you call functions with await inside of function ‘check’. Take a look the documentation https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: Thanks  

I taught it is web3 error without checking the error